# How to use opencv BOWKMeansTrainer in Java?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection

I am using opencv 3.2 for Java (build source with contrib modules), and trying to use SURF + BOWKMeansTrainer for detect, but it throws an error when I run it.

My code:

```
//read jpg to variable trainMats
//...

//train
Mat allDesc = new Mat();
int clusterCount = 30;
FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
DescriptorExtractor extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
BOWTrainer bowTrainer = new BOWKMeansTrainer(clusterCount);

for(int i = 0; i < trainMats.size(); i++) {
    Mat trainMat = trainMats.get(i);
    MatOfKeyPoint matOfKeyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    Mat desc = new Mat();
    detector.detect(trainMat, matOfKeyPoint);
    extractor.compute(trainMat, matOfKeyPoint, desc);
    allDesc.push_back(desc);
}

Mat dictionary = bowTrainer.cluster(allDesc);

//...
```

throw error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
    at org.opencv.features2d.BOWKMeansTrainer.cluster_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.features2d.BOWKMeansTrainer.cluster(BOWKMeansTrainer.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is by the OpenCV version.
Try using 2.4.11